# Android: preloading list activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a realtively complicated listview in my application, with data fetched from the internet and so on. What is the best practice to do to preload as much as possible of the ListView, such that it appears immediately on the screen?

For example, the standard SMS/MMS app of android shows a white screen with a spinning loader and "Loading..." before a conversation is shown. I can't really find this in the Android source code, but I guess this is an extra loading Activity doing some caching and handing over to the conversation Activity using finish(), so that no screen change animation is shown.

How can I preload or cache ListView items? Is it even possible to do that?

Thanks! Best regards, Jan Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done with the help of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (an intelligent backround thread) and [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

When the AsyncTask starts we raise a progressdialog with indeterminate state, once the task is finished we dismiss the dialog.

**Example code**
What the adapter does in this example is not important, more important to understand that you need to use AsyncTask to display a dialog for the progress.

```
private class PrepareAdapter1 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ContactsListCursorAdapter > {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(viewContacts.this);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait_while_loading));
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    @Override
    protected ContactsListCursorAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {
        cur1 = objItem.getContacts();
        startManagingCursor(cur1);

        adapter1 = new ContactsListCursorAdapter (viewContacts.this,
                R.layout.contact_for_listitem, cur1, new String[] {}, new int[] {});

        return adapter1;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ContactsListCursorAdapter result) {
        list.setAdapter(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Pentium10, thanks for the answer! That might help me a lot, although the time-consuming part in my application are the calls to the getView() method of the ListAdapter. But anyhow: isn't it necessary provide a an adapter for the ListView in the onCreate method? How did they do this here? With an empty dummy list or something? Also, this white screen with the loading animation is just a Progressdialog covering the whole screen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can provide an adapter on the listview, even if it's empty. You can then add items later to it, and you can call notifyDatasetChanged event to refresh the ListView. You can cache your views in some class object for later use.